# Is there a good way to ensure an object gets created before moving through code that uses it?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, fetch

I have a bit of code that uses `fetch()` to grab and convert **.tiff** images to an html5 canvas to be displayed in a browser using **tiff.js** (https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js/tree/master).  It almost works great, however, I am noticing that sometimes the images don't make it to the browser.

Some images will appear, but occasionally others will not, with the following error message in the browser:

`ReferenceError: Tiff is not defined`

I need to find out if there is a good way to ensure that these objects get created successfully, and would appreciate any insight I could get into what causes this behavior.

```
class tiffImage {
    constructor() {
        this.tiffURL = 'url-to-image';
        this.height;
        this.width;
        this.canvas;
    }

    async loadImage() {
        fetch(this.tiffURL)
            // retrieve tiff and convert it to an html5 canvas
            let response = await fetch(this.tiffURL);
            let buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
            let tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});  // error points to this line
            this.canvas = tiff.toCanvas();

            /* Parse some data from image and do DOM stuff */

    }

}

// retrieve and display boards
let someTiff1 = new tiffImage();
let someTiff2 = new tiffImage();
let someTiff3 = new tiffImage();
let someTiff4 = new tiffImage();
let someTiff5 = new tiffImage();

someTiff1.loadImage();
someTiff2.loadImage();
someTiff3.loadImage();
someTiff4.loadImage();
someTiff5.loadImage();
```

Sometimes all of the images are loaded probably, and sometimes not.  If the page is refreshed enough times it is guaranteed to see some images fail to load.  Note that in my actual project I am instantiating and calling `loadImage()` on 13 objects.

Comment: Yes: use the Promise that `fetch()` returns.

Comment: Why do you have `fetch(this.tiffURL)`, then `let response = await fetch(this.tiffURL);`? Also, the error seems to point to this "tiff.js" not being loaded before the `fetch` returns, which seems odd. You might want to look at where you're loading that library relative to your calls to `loadImage`...

Comment: @Pointy if you're confident in your comment could you elaborate?  From what I can see the problem is not in the ```fetch()``` call, but in the instantiation of the ```Tiff()``` object.

Comment: @Heritic Monkey nice catch!  I reduced the code to post an example and still didn't catch that mistake.  After removing that first ```fetch()``` call, the page either loads all or none of the images, instead of just loading some, which is interesting.

Comment: @Heritic Money it appears that I was loading the **tiff.js** library *after* the **tiff.min.js** file that contains the above code sample.  Reordering this seems to have corrected the issue.  I'll need to see it run for a while to really test it but it looks promising.  If you care to post your suggestion as an answer I will accept it, thank you!

Comment: The "min" file is a minified version of the same code in the non-min version, unless you named one of your files the same, which you shouldn't.

Comment: @Dave Newton for clarification, that was a typo.  I meant to say I was loading the **tiff.js** library *after* the **app.min.js** file that contains the above code sample, when it appears to need to be loaded before!

Comment: Well, yep, you usually need three code before you can use it-but ideally you wouldn't be running this code until the dom is ready anyway, e.g., on dom-ready.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises). A promise will allow you to wait for asynchronous actions to complete before progressing.

```
loadImage() {
    return fetch(this.tiffURL)
        .then(response=>{
        // retrieve tiff and convert it to an html5 canvas
        let buffer = response.arrayBuffer();
        let tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});  // error points to this line
        this.canvas = tiff.toCanvas();
        return this;

        /* Parse some data from image and do DOM stuff */
    }
}

Promise.all([someTiff1.loadImage(),someTiff2.loadImage()])
.then(results=>{
    console.log("My results", results)
})
```

Don't use `async` and `await` in your code. If you're using these, you're using Promises wrong.

Comment: Thank you for this response.  I appreciate this code sample and will implement your suggestions.  I would like to note however, that this answer is off topic as the solution to this particular issue was the order I was loading my scripts, which was suggested by @Heritic Monkey